# ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples [1,299]

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is data files [here](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_3e251a91db9262835c9e5855ae9e6573_perceptron-test.csv?Expires=1454976000&Signature=Qn~RxsR1tlP2pruLzkiIaAVO988Q2RaY1A9DEOINYYSJGRtX7pssvFc-09rbyWLwGrzdaAg5wAf0dXWyA6DPaJ2cBjcKu3iris~TuAR4liGjj2uFaV6pFdAYgrpXaLKNpOe5J~J3l7LZJ4qz7Sp3Prm0EQuFAGf5hsf0OErAmvs_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A) and [here](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_3e251a91db9262835c9e5855ae9e6573_perceptron-train.csv?Expires=1454976000&Signature=LRNSab2UYWhM7JdvEz3NkT6YDKZBnP-OhM-hyGGOKXxrvoyywj4VVhP8j3wQmFacR5vnhNeNNKcaQHbnX1OB8CmVDVg074Y79OwBcdAwbkyVd2FWYRIdQXRZ2lURrRIaPSI-NPUpcO6KAb0WHeqYbqo-lC91qrm0yG4Hemvy7ZQ_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A). You can download it by clicking on links the link. I am using Pandas, Numpy and Python3.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pa
import numpy as nu
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def get_accuracy(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    perceptron = Perceptron()
    perceptron.fit(X_train, y_train)
    perceptron.transform(X_train)
    prediction = perceptron.predict(X_test)
    result = accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)
    return result

test_data = pa.read_csv("C:/Users/Roman/Downloads/perceptron-test.csv")
test_data.columns = ["class", "f1", "f2"]
train_data = pa.read_csv("C:/Users/Roman/Downloads/perceptron-train.csv")
train_data.columns = ["class", "f1", "f2"]

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(train_data[train_data.columns[1:]]).reshape(-1,1)
X_train = scaler.transform(train_data[train_data.columns[1:]])

scaler.fit_transform(train_data[train_data.columns[0]])
y_train = scaler.transform(train_data[train_data.columns[0]])

scaler.fit_transform(test_data[test_data.columns[1:]])
X_test = scaler.transform(test_data[test_data.columns[1:]])

scaler.fit_transform(test_data[test_data.columns[0]])
y_test = scaler.transform(test_data[test_data.columns[0]])




scaled_accuracy = get_accuracy(nu.ravel(X_train), nu.ravel(y_train),    nu.ravel(X_test), nu.ravel(y_test))
print(scaled_accuracy)
```

And here is error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Roman/PycharmProjects/data_project-1/lecture_2_perceptron.py", line 33, in <module>
    scaled_accuracy = get_accuracy(nu.ravel(X_train), nu.ravel(y_train), nu.ravel(X_test), nu.ravel(y_test))
  File "C:/Users/Roman/PycharmProjects/data_project-1/lecture_2_perceptron.py", line 9, in get_accuracy
    perceptron.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 545, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 389, in _fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr', dtype=np.float64, order="C")
  File "C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 520, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 176, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))
**ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1 299]**
```

Without scaling data everything work fine. But after scaling not.

Comment: Would you please share the contents of your CSV files? I mean, if there is no data, there is no way the output can be replicated, you see!

Comment: Calling `fit_transform` returns the scaled data; try setting your `fit_transforms` equal to your X and y train/test objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247687/valueerror-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `fit_transform` each time you use scaler. You should `fit` it once, on the training data, and later only `transform`, otherwise you get different representation for training and testing (leading to error provided). There is also no point in scaling labels.